# AMP pages in Google search results on desktop

Tags: seo, google-search, wordpress, amp

I have a WordPress-based website with the "AMP for WP" plugin installed. It seems to be configured properly so that AMP pages point to respective non-AMP pages with "rel canonical", but I noticed some AMP pages showed up in Google search results even on a desktop browser.

What could cause that and how to make sure AMP pages are shown in SERP only for mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past, there have been [several bugs](https://twitter.com/cramforce/status/780824406201249793) related to AMP pages showing up in desktop searchers, that might be another one.

[image]

In addition to that, [Google has been suffering in the last 5 months several bugs](https://searchengineland.com/google-has-fixed-the-indexing-issue-from-thursday-night-317484) related to the indexation of new content. This is being a hard year for Google as they are changing a lot of things.

My guess is that **is just a bug that will be fixed in the short term** but it could also be a test to check how AMPs pages respond for certains searchers in desktop. Nothing official has been said about that in the past days.

Comment: Google is making everything under their control. A Good example is AMP.

Comment: Indeed. In addition to AMP we have PWA, Firebase, Google Cloud, Google CDN, booking in hotels and restaurants directly from the SERPs, etc.